# required field validation on android

Tags: android, validation

In android how do I create a required field validation? like on a page where use can enter some data into some `EditText`. I wanted to make sure user enter something before continuing, like if the user forgot to enter some data, the app would not crash. I have done other validation like number only using those input-type provided. but so far I research I only found ways to validate content entered but not whether there is something entered. 
So I should put something in the `onCreate` method like

```
if(EditText text is !=null){ do the stuff} else {error message}
```

But if I did that, the moment the app is run there will be error displayed. 
And how do I write the "text of EditText" in c# I believe is `TextBox` Text. But I do not know how to do that in java android. I know setText but do not know how to refer to the content without changing it.

Answer (score 0):

To get text user entered in the `EditText` you can call `getText()` method. I recommend you to perform validation after user clicks some button. Validating content of `EditText` inside `onCreate()` method is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to tell the user that they need to put the correct information the earliest possible. Why? Because it allows the user to quickly identify the problem and fix it. That being said, I would recommend checking if its null or whatever you want the textfield to contain as soon as it looses focus.

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //We get the text and then convert it to a string and check
           if(v.getText().toString() == ""){
           //Do what you want in this area
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = textview.getText().toString().trim()
```